# Search an array of odject

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

Imagen if I have an Array of objects - id and value. Right now the array is empty Array []. But is being fielded anytime the user type and add a name. If a user types Anna, Pedro, and Joana the array is updated to

```
    Array [
  Object {
    "id": "0.265247357395923",
    "value": "Anna",
  },
  Object {
    "id": "0.07416445026556007",
    "value": "Pedro",
  },
  Object {
    "id": "0.9097178194832282",
    "value": "Joana",
  },
]
```

My task is to add a Search bar where I can search the object value inside the array. Here's my code so far.

My useState

```
const [folder, emptyFolder] = useState([]);
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
```

My name

```
const addFolder = (folderName) => {
    emptyFolder((currentFolder) => [
      ...currentFolder,
      { id: Math.random().toString(), value: folderName },
    ]);
  };
```

My Search. Here is where I want to implement my code so far this is what I am able to do:

```
const filteredData = folder.filter((item) => {
    const textData = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
    const nameFolder = item.value.toUpperCase();
    return nameFolder.includes(textData);
  });

  const _searchFilterFunction = (value) => {
    //???
  };
```

Here is my Return where I have TextInput as my search bar and {filteredData.map((item, index) => { return {item.value}; })} displaying my name list every time the user creates.

```
return (
    <View style={styles.HomeContainer}>
      <TextInput
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
        placeholderTextColor="#9a73ef"
        style={styles.search}
        placeholder="Search"
        onChangeText={(value) => {
          _searchFilterFunction(value, folder);
        }}
      />
      <FolderInput myFolder={addFolder} />

      {filteredData.map((item, index) => {
        return <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>;
      })}
    </View>
  );
};
```

PLEASE HELP THANK YOU VERY MUCH.

Comment: `const textData = searchTerm.toUpperCase();` ... where is `searchTerm` set to anything useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter the array of objects(folders) like this:

```
const filteredFolders = () => {
  return state.folders.filter(({ name }) =>
    name.toLowerCase().includes(state.search.toLowerCase())
  );
}
```

Where state.search comes from an input. I [created a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-sound-dbuvy?file=/src/App.js) with working demo

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is, correct.

```
const filteredData = folder.filter((item) => {
    const textData = searchTerm.toUpperCase();
    const nameFolder = item.value.toUpperCase();
    return (nameFolder.indexOf(textData) >= 0)
});
```

`includes` is used for the array with string, but here actually you are comparing strings right? so you can go with `indexOf` it will return `true` if your search string is a substring of the object item.

Comment: How about my Search bar const _searchFilterFunction = (value) => {
    //???
  }; I want to do I search in here. If the user string is equal to the value in the array it will filter how the array and display the content. how do I do this?

Comment: if you want the exact match you can go with `return nameFolder === textData`. This `===` comparers both value and datatype and will return true if it is an exact match. I hope this is your query, if not can you elaborate?

Comment: `const _searchFilterFunction = (value) => {
   filteredData(value) 
  };`

Comment: @Arun Kumar My query is to create a search bar and search the value in my array of objects
I made some changes so you can understand better…
//I am mapping and  displaying the value in my list  
{folder.map((item) => {
       return <Text key={item.id}>{item.value}</Text>;
     })}
//I created a TextInput to search my item.value:
<TextInput
       onChangeText={(value) => {
         _searchFilterFunction(value, folder);
       }}
     />
_searchFilterFunction is my onChangeText function 
const _searchFilterFunction = (value, folder) => {
 };
I am stuck here Don't know what to do

Comment: @SohanPatil It didn't work thank you for trying to help

Comment: please try this `const _searchFilterFunction = (value) => {emptyFolder(filteredData(value)) };`